# Swift: How to save and display information based on a certain day

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, calendar

I am trying to save information in one view controller(ViewController1); lets say the amount of apples eaten in a day, and then be able to click on a calendar (using the CVcalendar cocoapod from github https://github.com/Mozharovsky/CVCalendar) and the number of apples eaten to appear for that particular day within a second view controller (ViewController2). I am struggling with how to:

a) Make the variable storing the number of apples eaten accessible to the viewcontroller showing the data within the calendar (ViewController2)and how to get the information stored in different arrays as the information will be stored automatically.

b) How to display the information within the second view controller on the day ( I tried to use a comparison of the NSDateComponents to compare the two and then display the data)

Comment: So basically in short, youre trying to find out how to send information from view controller #1 to viewcontroller #2 ?

Comment: In its most simple form yes. I want to be able to save a global variable (or maybe an array) containing two things; the date the action happened, and some information about what happened(e.g. number of apples eaten). I then want to be able to access this data from a second view controller

Comment: Well you should already know how to save information in an array on viewController #1. To pass information unto view controller #2, you can use the `prepareForSegue` funciton. You can google this and find an answer

Comment: The view controller arent linked by segues, they are both child view controllers from the main view controller so I would need the array to be global to access it surely?

Comment: They are child controllers of the main view controller. Are you able to get an instance of those child controllers from the main controller?  How are they child controllers -> do you load them through some variable? Once you can get an instance of those child controllers, you can do something like `childViewController.somevar = mainViewController.varToTransfer`